# Find matching pattern on streaming data using Python

Tags: python, xpath, apache-kafka, rule-engine

I'm receiving a stream of data in following format

```
a1 = {"name":"abc","city":"c1","code":"c1234"}
a1 = {"name":"abcd","city":"c1","code":"c3234"}
```

I need to find which pattern each of these belong to as they are received as message in KAFKA topic.

The patterns are like

```
p1 : name = 'abc' AND code="c1234"
p2 : city="c1"
p3 : name = 'abc'
```

Example 1 above should be mapped to p1 as it satisfies more conditions than p2, whereas second example should be mapped to p2.

I tried following

1. Tried using for loops, but that takes lot of time as incoming data & rules are many.
2. Tried to create rules in XML and use XPATH, but the nodes (name, city, code here) are not fixed. Rule can have only one or combination of many.
3. Created matrix like one-hot encoding and tried to match them.

Is there any other way to find out which pattern/ rule the incoming message should be tagged to?

Can this be handled in KAFKA?

Comment: You could use something like `Faust` but if you could adapt approach #3 and shard the initial partitioning logic into more manageable lookups you could trade memory for near-O(1) performance for each message.

Comment: Thanks @MarkR. - I tried using Faust. But struggling to finalize of logic which will be efficient and without too many loops.

Comment: What's the event rate per second?

Comment: Approx 60 per second